# Android layout doesn't refresh after calling removeAllViews()

Tags: android

I have a Linearlayout called "resultView". I then dynamically added many textViews in it after clicking a button.
I want to remove all the textviews that I just created when I click the button again.

```
btn_search.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            resultView.removeAllViews();

            String strFileName = et_fileName.getText().toString();
            searchFiles(strFileName);
    }
});

 public void searchFiles(String strFileName){
   ....

    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(fileList.get(i).getName());
        textView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

        if (fileList.get(i).isFile())
            resultView.addView(textView);
    }
}
```

[App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04JG9.png), All the listed results are dynamically created textViews.

[My XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C54KH.png), the id "view" is my resultView.

But `resultView.removeAllViews();` doesn't work. The results are still appened.
Calling `resultView.invalidate();` after that doesn't work either.

What should I do to make the layout refresh?

Comment: add also resultView.requestLayout();

Comment: resultView.requestLayout() not work

Comment: if you are not into mainThread use postInvalidate() instead of invalidate(). Were are you call invalidate() into your code? In "onClickListener" you remove only views.

Answer (score 0):

Use .invalidate() to upddate UI.